# How do String oops and mirror oops generate by Hotspot VM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

In openjdk8 source code, I find that some java.lang.String oop do not go through bytecode engine and allocate by jvm itself. As `hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp:185` says:

```
Handle java_lang_String::create_from_unicode(jchar* unicode, int length, TRAPS) {
  Handle h_obj = basic_create(length, CHECK_NH); // alloc size of java.lang.String oop
  typeArrayOop buffer = value(h_obj());
  for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    buffer->char_at_put(index, unicode[index]);  // put a char[] into this oop...
  }
  return h_obj;
}
```

As above, a *fake* String is created... however, `java.lang.String` has five member variables (fields), how do they initialize? In other words, how does these *fake* String oop become the real `java.lang.String` object?

Same as `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.Class` also does this things. At `hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp:553` says:

```
oop java_lang_Class::create_mirror(KlassHandle k, Handle protection_domain, TRAPS) {
    ...
    Handle mirror = InstanceMirrorKlass::cast(SystemDictionary::Class_klass())->allocate_instance(k, CHECK_0);
    ...
    // if `k` holds a InstanceKlass, it will initialize the static fields by constant value attribute. else do nothing...
}
```

I was very confused by this. Only `alloc` memory, if it is `java.lang.String`'s object, put a `char[]` into it; but when do the other fields in `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Class` fills in to the oop? Thank you.

Comment: As of Java 8, there are only *two* instance fields, the other fields are `static`; the `char[] value` is the only field needed to be initialized, as `hashCode` is initialized lazily within the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I totally understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java_lang_String::basic_create()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/8015f8f73cde/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp#l164) allocates `String` object and initializes its `value` field:

```
    obj = InstanceKlass::cast(SystemDictionary::String_klass())->allocate_instance(CHECK_NH);

    // Create the char array.  The String object must be handlized here
    // because GC can happen as a result of the allocation attempt.
    Handle h_obj(THREAD, obj);
    typeArrayOop buffer;
      buffer = oopFactory::new_charArray(length, CHECK_NH);

    // Point the String at the char array
    obj = h_obj();
    set_value(obj, buffer);   <<<--- char[] value is set here
  // No need to zero the offset, allocation zero'ed the entire String object
  assert(offset(obj) == 0, "initial String offset should be zero");
//set_offset(obj, 0);
  set_count(obj, length);
```

`hash` field is computed lazily. At allocation time it has the default value `0` since `allocate_instance` clears the entire object. There are no other `String` instance fields in JDK 8.

As to `java.lang.Class`, it has no fields to initialize at allocation time, because all its fields are kind of caches. They are set in Java code when needed. Again, the entire `Class` instance is zeroed by allocation routine.

Comment: Thanks! I find `java.lang.Class` only has one trivial constructor. `java.lang.String` has one `char[]` constructor and `StringTable::intern` injected a `TypeArrayOop` in it.